# Google cloud run endpoint (extensible) service proxy api gateway firebase token

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-cloud-api-gateway, google-api-gateway

- Super basic (video) but the title is nearly my comment to [Top 3 ways to run your containers on Google Cloud](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jh0fPT-AWwM&lc=Ugz3jJ3tfTBlrg12ho14AaABAg)
- [User Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64597885/11711280) (content) in 2020 about api gateway from endpoints
- Maybe a focal point for an answer could be the app engine role for api gateway in 2022. [`swagger.yaml`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71782426/google-cloud-api-gateway-cant-invoke-cloud-run-service-while-using-firebase-aut) (*#comment*)

```
# openapi2-run.yaml
swagger: "2.0"
info: # >1 API/service; spec x-google-api-name OpenAPI document extension.
  title: backbank # mastercard-backbank # API_ID optional-string
  #https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/get-started-cloud-run
  description: node cloud run api mastercard p.12 customer keys # Sample API on API Gateway with a Cloud Run backend
  version: 0.0.1
security:
  - firebase: []
securityDefinitions: #https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway/docs/authenticating-users-firebase
  firebase: #bearer https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-extensions
    authorizationUrl: "" # empty for firebase frm bearer Authorization?
    flow: "implicit"
    type: "oauth2"
    x-google-issuer: "https://securetoken.google.com/vaumoney"
    x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com"
    x-google-audiences: "vaumoney"
host: "vault-co.in"
basePath: "/" # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71258737/making-a-cloud-firestore-rest-api-call-through-cloud-endpoints
#When the basePath property is configured in the service configuration as well,
#this header applies only to URL paths that are prefixed by the basePath property value.
#URLs that aren't part of the basePath aren't passed through regardless of the x-google-allow property.

schemes:
  - https
consumes:
  - application/json
produces:
  - application/json
#x-google-allow:
  #all
  #jwt_audience: https://www.googleapis.com/service_accounts/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com/vaumoney
#x-google-endpoints:
  #- name: "vault-co.in"
    #allowCors: True
paths:
  /:
    get:
      summary: Yes Hello cloud run (api gateway, load balance) service
      operationId: get
      x-google-backend: 
        address: https://vault-co.in:8080 # APP_URL endpoint(s)
        protocol: h2
      responses:
        200:
          description: This is a (Non-Graphical) Application Programming Interface
          #schema:
          #type: string
          #default: '''ello guv'''

        default:
          description: Something is wrong
          #schema:
          #type: string
          #default: '''some not 200'''

    options:
      summary: Enable CORS with headers
      operationId: options
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://vault-co.in:8080 # APP_URL endpoint(s)
        jwt_audience: https://vault-co.in 
        protocol: h2
      description: |
        Origin, Methods and Headers allowing headers potentially requested
      tags:
        - CORS
      responses:
        200:
          description: OPTIONS responding headers
          headers:
            Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
              type: string
              #$ref: '#/definitions/String'
              default: "'i7l8qe.csb.app'"
            Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
              type: string
              default: "'GET,POST'"
            Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
              type: string
              default: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key'"
        403:
          description: OPTIONS responding headers
          headers:
            Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
              type: string
              default: "'i7l8qe.csb.app'" # '''vau.money'''
            Access-Control-Allow-Methods:
              type: string
              default: "'GET,POST'"
            Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
              type: string
              default: "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key'"
          #content: {}

        default:
          description: Something is wrong
          #type: string
          #default: '''some not 200'''

    post:
      summary: Respond properly indeed
      operationId: posted
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://vault-co.in:8080 # APP_URL endpoint(s)
        jwt_audience: https://vault-co.in 
        protocol: h2
      description: |
        Successful api fetch
      parameters:
        - name: pageOffset
          in: body
          required: true
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              pageOffset:
                description: pageOffset is required, try 0
                type: string
              pageLength:
                description: pageLength is required, try 10
                type: string
              postalCode:
                description: postalCode is required, try 11101
                type: string

      responses: # https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-responses/
        default: #200
          description: post result
          #content:v3 application/json:
          schema:
            type: object
            description: response ok
            required:
              - results
            properties:
              results:
                #collectionFormat: csv
                type: array
                default: []
                items:
                  type: string
              meta:
                type: object
                properties:
                  title:
                    type: string
                  description:
                    type: string
```

I [repeat attempts](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-local-firebase-i7l8qe?file=/src/fetch.js) in seriatim:

1. `gcloud api-gateway gateways delete backbank --location=us-central1`
2. `gcloud api-gateway api-configs delete backbank --api=backbank`
3. `gcloud api-gateway api-configs create backbank --api=backbank --openapi-spec=swagger.yaml --project=vaumoney --backend-auth-service-account=vaumoney@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`
4. (a) `gcloud endpoints services deploy swagger.yaml --project=vaumoney`
   (b) `gcloud services enable vault-co.in` (Principal-role permission name: "firebase-adminsdk")
5. `gcloud run deploy backbank \`
   `--image="gcr.io/vaumoney/endpoints-runtime-serverless:2.38.0-vault-co.in-2022-09-08r2" \`
   `--set-env-vars ESPv2_ARGS=^++^--cors_preset=cors_with_regex++--cors_allow_origin_regex=^https:[/][/]i7l8qe.csb.app$++--cors_allow_methods=GET,POST,OPTIONS++--cors_allow_headers=Origin,Content-Type,Authorization,Referrer-Policy++--cors_allow_credentials \`
   `--platform managed --project vaumoney`

Of course, I incessantly get this:

```
The request was not authenticated. Either allow unauthenticated invocations or set the proper Authorization header. Read more at https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/authenticating Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#unauthorized-client
```

But *OPTIONS* might be the problem (albeit "" on GET):

> "This would be [really useful](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/181537068) for us, we're using cloud run for all our microservices and want to call these from a SPA via API Gateway." "We're back to Cloud Endpoints and ESPv2 for the time being, but we 100% see the benefits of the managed API Gateway, should CORS support be available for gRPC requests."

What am I to do?

Comment: What do we need to achieve here? Based on the error you posted, your request was not authenticated and needed to either allow unauthenticated invocations or set a proper authorization header. Have you checked if the proper IAM permissions are set based on the links on the error? Also there are some limitations when using OpenAPI. Those were either ignored or unsupported. You may check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-limitations) for details.

Comment: @RobertG Should I use api gateway or endpoints to replace cloud functions? My steps 1-3 should be enough to emulate continuous development build image *in api gateway*, or cloud build *without*, and it seems api gateway deploys the endpoint for us. Is that right? I would like an example working using this `swagger.yaml` of the state of the art, but the commentary on google groups between the features gateway/endpoint is throwing me thru a loop.

Comment: I used `gcloud run deploy` so I am utilizing the ESPv2 startup, so I use root `/` path.  My `OAuth2` security definition is toward a [`firebase`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71782874/11711280) requirement. With api gateway, the endpoint proxy seems to be deployed (and with its ESP configured) for us, and be which maybe why this example answered 5 months ago with the port+`address` `x-google-backend` with address alone rather as `jwt_audience` in post method, which is not (?) to traverse **custom port limitation** on host without protocol scheme. Am I missing something from Šime's external auth

Comment: @RobertG My `App Engine default service account` (*vaumoney@appspot.gserviceaccount.com*) is used by my api config to call the api, with the roles *Cloud Run Invoker* that uses `roles/run.invoker`. Does this error happen with a successful bearer firebase token auth, for a process roles [e.g. *Secret Manager Secret Accessor*, on the same App Engine (?) service account]?

Comment: The error `The request was not authenticated` when building with `cloud run + endpoints` comes about in the api `Stackdriver` logging as "*jwt_authn_access_denied{Jwt_is_missing}*" for api gateway.